# How to assign time stamp to the command in Python?

Tags: python, string

There are several types of `Commands` in the third column of the text file. So, I am using the regular expression method to grep the number of occurrences for each type of command.

For example, `ACTIVE` has occurred 3 times, `REFRESH` 2 times. I desire to enhance the flexibility of my program. So, I wish to assign the time for each command.

Since one command can happen more than 1 time, if the script supports the command being assigned to the time, then the users will know which `ACTIVE` occurs at what time. Any guidance or suggestions are welcomed.

The idea is to have more flexible support for the script.

My code:

```
import re
a = a_1 = b = b_1 = c = d = e = 0

lines = open("page_stats.txt", "r").readlines()

for line in lines:
    if re.search(r"WRITING_A", line):
        a_1 += 1
    elif re.search(r"WRITING", line):
        a += 1
    elif re.search(r"READING_A", line):
        b_1 += 1
    elif re.search(r"READING", line):
        b += 1
    elif re.search(r"PRECHARGE", line):
        c += 1
    elif re.search(r"ACTIVE", line):
        d += 1
```

File content:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Number        | Time |     Command    |      Data             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1             | 0015 | ACTIVE         |                       |
| 2             | 0030 | WRITING        |                       |
| 3             | 0100 | WRITING_A      |                       |
| 4             | 0115 | PRECHARGE      |                       |
| 5             | 0120 | REFRESH        |                       |
| 6             | 0150 | ACTIVE         |                       |
| 7             | 0200 | READING        |                       |
| 8             | 0314 | PRECHARGE      |                       |
| 9             | 0318 | ACTIVE         |                       |
| 10            | 0345 | WRITING_A      |                       |
| 11            | 0430 | WRITING_A      |                       |
| 12            | 0447 | WRITING        |                       |
| 13            | 0503 | PRECHARGE      |                       |
| 14            | 0610 | REFRESH        |                       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to count the occurrences of each command and store
the timestamps of each command as well, would you please try:

```
import re
count = {}
timestamps = {}
with open ("page_stats.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.split(r"\s*\|\s*", line)
        if len(m) > 3 and re.match(r"\d+", m[1]):
            count[m[3]] = count[m[3]] + 1 if m[3] in count else 1
            if m[3] in timestamps:
                timestamps[m[3]].append(m[2])
            else:
                timestamps[m[3]] = [m[2]]

# see the limited result (example)
#print(count["ACTIVE"])
#print(timestamps["ACTIVE"])

# see the results
for key in count:
    print("%-10s: %2d, %s" % (key, count[key], timestamps[key]))
```

Output:

```
REFRESH   :  2, ['0120', '0610']
WRITING   :  2, ['0030', '0447']
PRECHARGE :  3, ['0115', '0314', '0503']
ACTIVE    :  3, ['0015', '0150', '0318']
READING   :  1, ['0200']
WRITING_A :  3, ['0100', '0345', '0430']
```

- `m = re.split(r"\s*\|\s*", line)` splits `line` on a pipe character which
  may be preceded and/or followed by blank characters.
- Then the list elements `m[1]`, `m[2]`, `m[3]` are assingned to the `Number`, `Time`, `Command`
  in order.
- The condition `if len(m) > 3 and re.match(r"\d+", m[1])` skips the
  header lines.
- Then the dictionary variables `count` and `timestamps` are assigned,
  incremented or appended one by one.